# wcstombs doesn't work properly

Tags: c, visual-studio, unicode

I have an utf-8 file which I can process normally with widechar functions.

However now I need to convert and use them in multibyte form and I'm struggling to make it work.

```
printf("%s\n",setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")); //English_United States.1252
_setmbcp(_MB_CP_LOCALE);
FILE *f = NULL;
f = _wfopen(L"data.txt", L"r,ccs=UTF-8");
wchar_t x[256];
fwscanf(f, L"%ls", x); //x = L"một"
char mb[256];
int l = wcstombs(mb, x, 256); //mb = "m?t"
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your textfile you have the character `ộ` (note the point below the character) instead of `ô`.

The character `ô` exists in [codepage 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), but the character `ộ` doesn't, and therefore `wcstombs` transforms it into a `?`.

You will have the same problem if your UTF-8 encoded text file contains for example cyrillic or greek characters.

The only solution is not having characters that don't have a representation in codepage 1252.

Comment: Or use an UTF-8 locale?

Comment: @FelixPalmen this sounds interesting, could you elaborate?

Comment: AFAIK `wcstombs` uses the current locale for its output (mbs = *multi-byte string* suggests this can be a multi-byte encoding like UTF-8) I didn't verify this. It would of course be silly in OPs example, because he's reading from an UTF-8 file using a conversion to `wchar_t`, so `wcstombs` would just convert it back to the original state with an UTF-8 locale.

Comment: Next question would be whether windows supports this. It definitely **does** support UTF-8 output with the similar winapi function `WideCharToMultiByte()`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen In my pc, the UTF-8 locale doesn't seem to exist since setlocale return null.